# How to Update/Change user account name in H2 database using JDBC?

Tags: jdbc, h2

What query should be used to change the username of H2 database in embedded mode with JDBC? I need to update the username with the input string from the user.

Comment: Which username? The name of the user account that was used to log-in to H2? A username in a table? A different user account inside the database?

Comment: Yes the user account name

Comment: http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#alter_user_rename

Answer (score 4):

Use this query 
Note:The password will become invalid when the user name was changed

```
alter user "+username+" rename to "+newusername+"//alter username
alter user"+newusername+" set password '"+password+"' //alter password
```